# Date Picker is not displaying in the browser

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, razor, telerik, asp.net-mvc-4

My Code:

```
@using Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI;
@using Telerik.Web.UI;

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($)
</script>
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
    .Name("DatePickerDOB")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 140px; " })
)

@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <p>
                To learn more about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://asp.net/mvc" title="ASP.NET MVC Website">
                    http://asp.net/mvc</a>. The page features <mark>videos, tutorials,
                        and samples</mark> to help you get the most from ASP.NET MVC. If you have
                any questions about ASP.NET MVC visit <a href="http://forums.asp.net/1146.aspx/1?MVC"
                    title="ASP.NET MVC Forum">our forums</a>.
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>
}
<h3>We suggest the following:</h3>
<ol class="round">
    <li class="one">
        <h5>Getting Started</h5>
        ASP.NET MVC gives you a powerful, patterns-based way to build dynamic websites that
        enables a clean separation of concerns and that gives you full control over markup
        for enjoyable, agile development. ASP.NET MVC includes many features that enable
        fast, TDD-friendly development for creating sophisticated applications that use
        the latest web standards. <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245151">Learn
            more</a></li>
    <li class="two">
        <h5>Add NuGet packages and jump start your coding</h5>
        NuGet makes it easy to install and update free libraries and tools. <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245153">
            Learn more</a></li>
    <li class="three">
        <h5>Find Web Hosting</h5>
        You can easily find a web hosting company that offers the right mix of features
        and price for your applications. <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=245157">Learn
            more</a></li>
</ol>
```

**I don't know what I have to do further for displaying the DatePicker when I am clicking the datepicker text field.** Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Is  @(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar() being referenced in _Layout?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with

```
@(Html.Telerik().DatePicker()
    .Name("DatePickerDOB")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 140px; " })
)
```

It works fine in my project (although the calendar opens when clicking the icon, not the textbox, but I don't think that's actually your question at this point).

Check to be certain that

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
```

is being called. Noramlly this is in _Layout, but can be put directly in the file using a Telerik control.

On a side note (I don't think it's causing your problem, but certainly isn't helping anything), these lines are wrong:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.css"></script>
```

.css files aren't scripts.  They should be referenced like this:

```
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

And you don't seem to actually be using any jQuery on this page, so you probably don't need to import all those scripts and css files anyway.  Telerik uses its own jQuery scripts, that's what the script Registrar is for.

Comment: I tried all the above various options. But nothing helps me to display the DatePicker. Thanks